# Making a simple calendar

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I've been trying to connect a very simple setup with my mySQL.

I might be way too naive, but I don't see why this wont work!

This is how I've tried to fetch the date of tomorrow, look for events, and echo the title.

```
<div class="ribbon">
    <p class="dato">
    <?php
        $now = new DateTime();
        $now->modify('+1 day');
        $now->format('Y-m-d');
        $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM kalender WHERE dato = '$now'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            echo $row['title'];
        }
    ?>
   </p>
</div>
```

I'm sorry for wasting anyones time. I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using object of `DateTime` instead of formatted date & `mysql` instead of `mysqli`.

```
<div class="ribbon"> 
<p class="dato"> 
<?php
$now = new DateTime();
$now->modify('+1 day');
$date = $now->format('Y-m-d'); // store in another variable & use it
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM kalender WHERE dato='$date'"); // mysqli instead of mysql
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) // if using only keys, use _assoc
{ 
    echo $row['title'];
}
?>
</p>
</div>
```